# How to access reports from another

Tags: reports-api

unaccept

Salesforce provides a rich collection of standard report types that you can tailor to your unique requirements.

```
Account and Contact Reports
```

Use account and contact reports to learn about active, neglected, or new accounts, as well as accounts by account owner or partner. The two standard contact reports let you create a mailing list of contacts or track opportunities by contact role

Comment: What are you actually trying to understand. - [ask]. Report Folders only really have 2 types - reports and dashboards. If it is types of report then there are all the standard ones, plus the ability to create custom types meaning there is no definitive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce provides a rich collection of standard report types that you can tailor to your unique requirements.

- Account and Contact Reports

Use account and contact reports to learn about active, neglected, or new accounts, as well as accounts by account owner or partner. The two standard contact reports let you create a mailing list of contacts or track opportunities by contact role.

- Activity Reports

Activity reports are useful for gathering information about open activities, completed activities, multi-person events, or pending approval requests for which you are a delegated approver.

- Administrative Reports

Administrative reports help you analyze your Salesforce users, documents, and pending approval requests. You can report on the active Salesforce users and see who has been logging in.

- Campaign Reports

Use campaign reports to analyze your marketing efforts. You can report on the ROI of your campaigns, track who you targeted with your campaigns and who has responded, or analyze which opportunities resulted from your campaigns.

- File and Content Reports

Run File and Content reports to analyze how users are engaging with files and Salesforce CRM Content.

- Forecast Reports

Forecast reports give you information about your customizable forecast data.

- Lead Reports

Use lead reports to show information about the source and status of leads, how long it takes to respond to leads, neglected leads, and the history of lead fields.

- Opportunity Reports

Opportunity reports provide information about your opportunities, including owners, accounts, stages, amounts, and more. The default settings show you the most commonly used information from each object, but you can customize a report to view other information, such as primary campaign source, forecast category, and synced quote.

- Product and Asset Reports

Use product and asset reports to view information about the products your users currently have installed. Find out what assets your customers have, list the cases filed for a particular asset, or identify assets that aren’t associated with a product.

- Self-Service Reports

Self-Service reports help you analyze the effectiveness of your Self-Service portal. Find out how many cases are being viewed, how many customers are logging in, or what customers think of the solutions you’re offering.

- Reporting on Support Activity

Use support reports to track the number of cases created, case comments, case emails, case owners, case contact roles, cases with solutions, the length of time since the case last changed status or owner, and the history of cases.

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=standard_report_folders.htm)